# Phrase for when you pretend to put up resistance to something but really you want it to happen?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For example if someone says "Do you want a beer?" there’s a phrase which means "you've convinced me" or "if you're going to force me". It's as if they've had to put in effort to make you say yes when you haven't really.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I heard hard?

Comment: Sounds like [*playing hard to get*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/all-we-need-is-love/202007/whos-playing-hard-get-who-s-attracted-it-and-why#:~:text=Playing%20hard%2Dto%2Dget%20means,struggle%20to%20get%20your%20attention.).

Answer (score 4):

Do you really want me to answer your question? OK, you’ve twisted my arm.